# folder structure for storing images

Tags: image, data-structures, directory

I have users who will have 2 types of picture images, + avatar image.

Which way is better

Users/picture1,Users/picture2, Users/avatar ?

Or

Picture1,Picture2,Avatar

Names of images will be stored in DB anyway.
So the question is better to store all avatars in one big folder or make separate folder for each user and there inside users folder make folders for avatar, picture and etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since folders are limited to a maximum number of files (not sure the actual number) then it probably makes sense to divide up the images by user. Of course, if the number of users is very, very large then you could hit a limit on the number of sub-folders.

Can the user have multiple avatar images and/or picture images (more than 2)? If not then it may be overkill to separate the avatar and picture images. Putting them in a single "User" folder or "User/images/" folder may be easiest.

Comment: what's the normal amount of user folders? 1million? 10 millions ? Where is the limit ?

Comment: It is really a performance thing as opposed to a hard limit. The actual numbers depend on the OS (Windows or Linux), parition format (FAT, FAT32, NTFS, etc.), 32-bit or 64-bit, etc. According to this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28WS.10%29.aspx. The article mentions 300,000 but I suspect you will start hurting way below that number (30-40k).

Comment: well let's say NTFS 64bit can u give me some number from which I can start thinking ?